# How to make table caption appear after TABLE I. in IEEE latex format

Tags: tables, captions, ieeetran

I am using the IEEE conference format for my paper. The captions of the tables should be like

> TABLE I. Caption

but they appear like

> TABLE I
>
> Caption

I have tried

```
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=period}%
```

but it changes the whole style of the caption.

Is there another way of doing this without changing the style?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide MWE @user8724849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch `\@makecaption`. But be aware that such journal styles are like the journal wants them and you normally shouldn't change the style.

```
\documentclass[conference]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@makecaption{\\}{.~}{}{\fail}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{blub}
a table
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the problem. I know that I shouldn't tamper with the conference format but I think the*.cls they provided is faulty because when I compile the tex, the output file doesn't look like the template (microsoft word file) they have provided.